# Why is this instance object being changed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fmdb

I'm very new at objective C, I'm just learning. I did the techotopia tutorial "An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application_(Xcode_4)", then tried to implement it again with FMDB. (I'd post the link to the tutorial but it let's me only post 2 links max)

The problem: In `initWithFrame` I create `eventDB`. Then in `addEvent`, after a keypress, the `eventDB.database`'s contents are changed. [This](http://i.minus.com/dbwg8WAcAvIx0l.png) is `eventDB` in `initWithFrame` and [this](http://i.minus.com/dv8y4fJuWwonK.png) is it in `addEvent`.

```
#import "appTracker.h"
@implementation appTracker

- (id) initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    eventDB = [[appTrackerDB alloc] init];
    return self;
}


- (void) keyDown: (NSEvent *) event
{

    NSString *chars = [event characters];
    unichar character = [chars characterAtIndex: 0];
    if (character == 'A') {
        NSLog (@"Adding event");
        [self addEvent:@"test_arg"];            
    }
}

- (void) addEvent: (NSString *) name
{
    [eventDB setName:name];
    [eventDB setPhone:name];
    [eventDB setAddress:name];
    [eventDB setStatus:name];
    [eventDB saveData];
}
...
@end
```

Using GDB I stepped through and found that it is changing in `main.m` (autogenerated by XCode4) here:     (not really sure what this code does or why it's there)

```
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);
}
```

I'm unfamiliar with objective C. Can someone help me figure out why my `eventDB.database` object is being changed? I'm probably not managing some memory correctly or totally misinterpreting how you are supposed to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

`eventDB` is an instance of:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FMDatabase.h"

@interface appTrackerDB : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
    NSString *address;
    NSString *phone;
    NSString *status;
    NSString *databasePath;
    FMDatabase *database;
}
```

Thanks!

Also [eventDB saveData] is:

```
- (void) saveData
{
    [database executeUpdate:@"insert into user (name, address, phone) values(?,?,?)",
     name, address, phone,nil];
}
```

And created the database with:

```
@implementation appTrackerDB
@synthesize name,address,status,phone;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];

        database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
        [database open];

        [database executeUpdate:@"create table IF NOT EXISTS user(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)"];
        if ([database hadError]) {
            NSLog(@"DB Error %d: %@", [database lastErrorCode], [database lastErrorMessage]);
        }
        name = @"TEST";
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Don't you want it to change? I mean you are setting the name and address properties when addEvent is called, that changes the object.

Or are you talking about replacing the Object? (e.g. the pointer value changes)

maybe you should elaborate a little bit more on what actually your problem is.

Comment: I dont want `eventDB.database`'s contents to change. I don't change those.

Comment: aehm... then what does [eventDB saveData]; do, if it isn't saving data to the database?

Comment: Sorry I see the confusion. The issue is not that the contents of the database are change, rather that the reference to the database is changed. If you look at the two images in the question you can see what I mean. Also just for completeness I added the code for saveData.

Comment: ok i see what you mean. How did you initialize the actual FMDatabase? The documentation suggests three different ways, which could explain your problem.

Comment: I updated the post with the initialization code. That is the only code I run to create the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually retain the Database. In Objective-C you need to **manually** retain the Objects, especially if they are not properties. (e.g. `name` is declared as a property, `database` is not)

Retaining means that you own the Object. `databaseWithObject` retains the Database but calls `autorelease` on it, which normally means, it will delete the reference as soon as possible after the calling method is finished.

Depending on your platform, e.g. OS X instead of iOS, you could enable the *GarbageCollection*-feature. This would mean, that the OSX/Objective-C environment would do a lot of the memory management for you. But for this to be of any use, you would need to the declare the pertaining instance variables as properties **and** use the appropriate setter- and getter-methods on them.

Here is an example of a property-declaration (*appTrackerDB.h*):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FMDatabase.h"

@interface appTrackerDB : NSObject {
  /*
    These are only necessary when 
    using iOS-Versions prior to
    iOS 4, or if you really
    need to manipulate the values 
    without utilizing the setter-/getter-
    methods.
  */
  NSString *name;
  NSString *address;
  NSString *phone;
  NSString *status;
  NSString *databasePath;
  FMDatabase *database;
}
@property (retain) NSString *name,*address;
@property (retain) NSString *phone,*status,*databasePath;
@property (retain) FMDatabase *database;
```

*appTrackerDB.m*:

```
@implementation appTrackerDB
@synthesize name,address,status,phone;
@synthesize databasePath,database;
```

An example setter method you would call instead of you manual assignment is:

- `[self setDatabase:...];` instead of assigning a value directly `database = ...`

Setter methods like `setVariableName` and getter methods like `variableName`
are synthesized for you by the `@synthesize` directive.

Comment: I made it a property with 
`@property (retain, nonatomic) FMDatabase *database;`
, synthesized it, and still the problem persists. Do I have to manually retain it now?

Comment: You have to call `[self setDatabase:[FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path]];` in init instead of the `database =..` variant

Comment: That did it! Thanks. What does this do differently?

Comment: this method, called a setter sets the variable as you did manually but also retains the object. its a more easy way for people who don't want to get into the very intimate mechanics of objective-c (most people don't need to)

Comment: Since this is on OSX, is there some garbage collection thing setting I can enable so that I wouldn't have to use `[self setDatabase:...];`?

Comment: no, even the garbage collection requires you to use the setter and getter methods declared by the combination of `@property` and `@synchronize`